# GCP Bigquery authotrized views

Tags: google-cloud-platform, view, google-bigquery, authorization

I have been applying the authorized views in the BigQuery. I know the general idea and rules - add an authorized access to run some queries by target view without giving an direct access to the underlying source data, like bellow:

```
table (layer_1) <- authorized_view (layer_2)
```

But currently I get stucked with situation like this - I have go the three layers of the data like follows.

```
table (layer_1) <- view (layer_2) <- authorized_view (layer_3)
```

And I don'tknow how to define the authorization source:
1. views in the layer 2 only
2. tables in the layer 1 only
3. both tables in layer 1 and vies in layer 2

Any ideas? The point 1 passes in the GCP, but unfortunatelly I have no other account to check if the whole solution is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have just veryfied on the another account - we have to add two authorizations:
1. authorization to table (layer 1) for view (layer 2)
2. authorization to view (layer 3) for view (layer 3)

```
table (layer_1) <- view (layer_2) <- authorized_view (layer_3)
```